# Issue with jquery countdown not updating count (reward offered)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout

OK, this is a bit of a tricky one, and I've got a deadline. So anybody who can solve this riddle in the next six hours (by 7am pacific time) gets $100 sent to them via paypal. If not, you still have my undying gratitude for solving the mystery.

I've got an idangero.us swiper with three slides in it. In each slide is a jquery countdown timer from here: http://github.com/rendro/countdown/

Here's how this thing is supposed to work:

When the page loads, you should see a timer count from 3-1 over 3 seconds. When the countdown is finished, it toggles a couple of things. Then there's supposed to be a five second delay, after which, it should automatically slide to the next slide, and the process should repeat. If you manually swipe to another slide, the process should also start over on that slide. Problem is that the timer count doesn't reset. The amount of time does, but the number doesn't. And the timeout function is kinda sketchy. It seems like it skips a beat sometimes.

[Here is a dumbed down live example](http://bushidodesigns.net/ss/video2.php)

[And here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tactics/jeL5X/1/)

And the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

/* initialize swiper */
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.videos',{
loop:true,
grabCursor: true,
onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper, direction) {
    $(".countdown").data('countdown').update(+(new Date) + 3000).start();
}
})

/* create countdown */
$(function() {
$('.countdown').countdown({
date: +(new Date) + 3000,
render: function(data) {
$(this.el).text(this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 0));
},
/* when countdown ends, do this */
onEnd: function() {
$(this.el).addClass('ended');
$(".swiper-slide-active").addClass("loaded");
/* when video is loaded, start timer, and slide to next video */
setTimeout( function() { 
$(".swiper-slide").removeClass('loaded');
mySwiper.swipeNext();   
},5000);
}

});
});

});
```

Comment: It's on the onSlideChangeEnd that the timer don't reset ?

Comment: DeanH your jquery selector $(".countdown") is pointing to an array om jquery dom elements. It shows about 4 of them. i'm guessing these would be the countdowns for each of the sliders. If you can just determine which slide you are on currently(between 1-4) you should be about to use $($(".countdown")[SlideNumber]).data('countdown').update(+(new Date) + 3000).start(); to update your counter. Also your counter is firing 5 times once the first slide finishes. You should try to make only one fire or load per slide. Otherwise it might mess around with your onslidechangeevent

Comment: Thanks. Can you clone the fiddle and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

So

Hello im not sure, but You did tried to use function named setInterval...

`timerId = setInterval(function()
    {
               // 
    }`

and then to reset it:

`clearInterval(timerId)`

Another thing is that the countdown ist working. Is method *render* really exist in jQuery countdown?

Try following:

```
/* create var*/

var counter = +(new Date) + 3000;

/* create countdown */
$(function() {
$('.countdown').countdown({
until: counter
},

$('.countdown').countdown(destroy ? 'destroy' : {until: counter });
```

Maybe destroying and creating countdown every slide would work.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html